# Unable to Close Form when using DragMove, MouseDown and Custom Button on same Grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an image which has a `MouseDown` event so that I can close the window: The image also has a Hover via `Style.Trigger`: *The code is minimized for simplicity*.

```
private void btnClose_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}
```

Because the Window is Borderless (`WindowStyle = none`), I added a MouseDown event so that I can drag it.

```
private void appWindow_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        this.DragMove();
    }
}
```

The problem is: If I am using the `MouseDown` with `DragMove()`, I cannot get the image used as buttons to work. If I comment out the DragMove, then the buttons works.

***XAML:***

```
<Image ToolTip="Close" Cursor="Hand" x:Name="btnClose" 
Width="26" Height="26" Margin="505,19,19,306" MouseUp="btnClose_MouseUp">
    <Image.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="img/closeNormal.png"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="img/closeHoverWithNoBackground.png"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Resources>
</Image>
```

All are in the same Grid.

I am also off the grid with ideas to solve this:

Answer (score 0):

try calling base.MouseLeftButtonDown

```
 protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
      base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);

      if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
      {
          this.DragMove();
      }
 }
```